# This bag has reds, yellows, grays, blacks, and wheels

Tags: set-identification

This bag has reds, yellows, grays, blacks, and wheels.  Includes a shovel.[image]

Answer (score 5):

[60183-1 Heavy Cargo Transport](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=60183-1) based on White Tile, Round 2 x 2 with Open Stud, Red Plate, Modified 1 x 8 with Door Rail, Dark Bluish Gray Plate, Round 4 x 4 with Hole

[image: 60183]